# Regex match between two strings that might contain another string

Tags: c#, regex

I'm doing a regex that is trying to match the following string:

```
.\SQL2012
```

From the two strings (they are contained within another larger string but that is irrelevant in this case):

```
/SERVER "\".\SQL2012\""
/SERVER .\SQL2012
```

So the `"\"` before and the `\""` after the match may both be omitted in some cases. The regex I've come up with (from a previous question here on StackOverflow) is the following:

```
 (?<=\/SERVER\s*(?:[""\\""]+)?)\w+(?=(?:[\\""""]+|$)| )
```

Which works fine if I'm trying to match `TEST_SERVER` instead of `.\SQL2012` (because `\w` does not match special characters). Is there a way to match anything until `\""` or a whitespace occurs?

I'm doing this in C#, here's my code:

```
string input = "/SERVER \"\\\".\\SQL2012\\\"\"";
string pattern = @"(?<=\/SERVER\s*(?:[""\\""]+)?)\w+(?=(?:[\\""""]+|$)| )";
Regex regEx = new Regex(pattern);
MatchCollection matches = regEx.Matches(input);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.ToString());
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: This smells of X/Y problem: you have problem X, you think you can solve it with solution Y, you found a problem in solution Y and now you're asking for a solution to your problem in solution Y while solution Y might not be the best way to solve problem X. What is problem X?

Comment: @NateKerkhofs That might just be the most convoluted comment I've read on SO. I don't see how the question isn't understandable on it's own.

Comment: The question is perfectly understandable on its own, that's true. What I'm talking about is http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem. Your Regex attempts to solve a problem that is unknown to us. However, your Regex might not be the BEST solution to the problem. What I'm interested in is what the problem is that you're attempting to solve using the Regex, in case there is a better solution to solve the problem than Regex.

Comment: While you were trying to go all meta on my question Avinash managed to answer it.

Comment: Do you understand why I went meta on your question though? Regex might not be the best solution to your actual problem. It's possible that there's a better solution to your problem that you solved using Regex. I'm just trying to help. We have no context except that you're trying to find ".\SQL2012" in a string that used to be part of another string. We don't know why you're trying to find that or why you're using that method. Checking your previous question, it looks like you're trying to extract a server name from a String. Is that a configuration string?

Comment: No I don't, you're assuming that the users are incapable of scaling their questions for context by themselves.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60229/discussion-between-nate-kerkhofs-and-soren-qvist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a word boundary `\b` just before to the lookahead,

```
string input = "/SERVER .\\SQL2012";
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(?<=\/SERVER\s+""\\"").*?\b(?=\\""""|$| )|(?<=\/SERVER\s+).*?\b(?= |$)");
foreach (Match m in rgx.Matches(input))
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[0].Value);
Console.WriteLine(input);
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/nR296i)

Comment: This matches "\".\SQL2012

Comment: What if the string is "somethingelse /SERVER \"\\\".\\SQL2012\\\"\" /something 3" (C# string), then the following is matched: "\".\SQL2012\"" /something

Comment: just get into here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60229/discussion-between-nate-kerkhofs-and-soren-qvist